# strptime does not yield deterministic results

Tags: c++, file-io, strptime

I have the following function, which reads csv files into a class.

```
int Class::loadFromFile(std::string filename){

  /** read file **/
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream file (filename);

  if( !(file.is_open()) ){
    FILE_LOG(logWARNING) << "File " << filename << " could not be opened.";
  }

  /** fields: datetime, value **/
  while( getline(file,line) )
    {
      std::vector<std::string> sline = split(line,',');

      // sline[0] is timestamp
      time_t timestamp;
      std::tm _timestamp;
      strptime(sline[0].c_str(),"%Y-%m-%d%n%T",&_timestamp);
      timestamp = mktime(&_timestamp);

      // sline[1] is value
      unsigned int value = stoi(sline[1]);

      std::cout << sline[0].c_str() << std::endl; // is always the same
      std::cout << timestamp << std::endl; // sometimes differs by 1 hour ONLY FOR THE FIRST LINE

      this->add(timestamp,value);
    }

  return 0;

 }
```

As commented in the code, the output of

```
std::cout << timestamp << std::endl;
```

for the very first line in my csv file is not always the same at each separate call of my program, but sometimes it differs by exactly one hour.

It seems strange that this happens only for the first line of the csv file and all other lines are interpreted exactly the same each time when I call the program.

Does anybody have an idea why that happens?

Comment: Perhaps the first line of your CSV file contains column names, not data? Please post a sample of the CSV file you are trying to read.

Comment: Try zero-initializing your `tm`:  `std::tm _timestamp{};`.  Also see https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date for a modern way to handle dates and times.  It is much easier to use than the ancient C API.